# How to Open Lightning file card in preview mode

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Using below component for content review:

```
<aura:component  
implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" access="global" controller="PC_SalesTilesDetails">
<aura:attribute name="id" type="String"/> 
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="ContentdocIds" type="Id" /> 
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doinit}"/>
<lightning:fileCard fileId="{!v.ContentdocIds}"/>
```

I need to avoid that click it should directly open it like this:

Trying to achieve following functionality

- Iam opening  document in new Tab.
- trying to avoid click functionality.
- If I come to new tab It should open in largesize

Anyone please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use lightning file card inside a modal popup. so onclick it will show preview of that file. 
refer this http://sfdcmonkey.com/2018/10/29/open-files-lightning-component/
in this they explained how to get file preview.